# Python Selenium cannot read cookies after redirecting to another website

Tags: python, selenium

I try reading the website cookies after logging in, but the following code cannot read it.
After the code runs, the `driver_cookies` I get is just an empty list. However, I can manually find the cookies in Chrome Development Tools.

```
driver.find_element(by=By.ID,value='login_id').send_keys(login_id)
driver.find_element(by=By.ID,value='password').send_keys(password)
driver.find_element(by=By.ID,value='login_btn').click()

while(driver.current_url!="https://www.theWebsiteThatWeGoTo.com"):
    continue
time.sleep(3)

# debug, the cookies can be found in the development tools after the code run here, 
# but the following code just cannot read it.
os.system("pause")

driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
driver_cookies = driver.get_cookies()
print(driver_cookies)
```

Something that I think I need to mention is the website, which the login website redirects to, uses a different protocol because it is used for an electron application and thus Chrome cannot directly load the page (will show `ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH`). I don't know if it is the reason.

Comment: we can't see this page, we can't run this code - so we have no idea what can make problem.

Comment: why do you switch to other window? It gets cookies from other window.